# ActiveRecord scoping with nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not sure if I'm just not searching the right thing, but I'm looking to set a scope to then use as a collection for a select box.

Notebook model:

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end
```

Note model:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notebook
end
```

I have several attributes on a note, the important attribute (for this) being `note_type`. For now, the note_type can be `check_list`, `text`, or `bookmark`.

**My goal is to have something like this working:**

```
Notebooks.notes_without_check_lists
```

to scope down so a user can *only* select from the dropdown Notebooks that do not contain any `notes` with the `note_type` being `check_list`. I'm just not sure where I should be doing the iteration over each `note` to determine whether or not it's parent `notebook` can be included in the collection.

**EDIT**
Currently, I have 4 `Notebook` records. Out of the four records, only one contains a note with the note type of check_list. That notebook contains two notes in total, only one of which has the note type of `check_list`. Because this is true, I'd like to exclude that entire notebook from the scope, regardless of the other notes in the notebook.

Any help is certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  scope :notes_without_check_lists, -> { joins(:notes).where.not(notes: { note_type: 'check_list' }).group('notebooks.id') }
end
```

Basically you perform a database query pulling all notebooks' notes where `note_type` is not equal to `check_list`.

## EDIT

After you edited the question, here is the solution using Ruby (inefficient with big collection of `notebooks`/`notes` to process) - will still think about solving it with ActiveRecord:

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

  def self.notes_without_check_lists
    all.reject { |notebook| notebook.notes.any? { |note| note.note_type == 'check_list' } }
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is really close. However, I'm actually getting more records back using this than the total I have in the database. For example, I have 4 notebook objects in total, only one of which actually contains a note with a check list. This is returning all four records, plus a copy of the third record. I'm doing some more investigation, but wanted to thank you for getting me at least somewhere with this code.

Comment: If I use `joins(:notes).where(notes: { note_type: 'check_list' })`, I get the one record back that contains the check list, so that's working as expected in the opposite way.

Comment: @jeepagooster I have edited the answer, note the `group` part. If that works (it will 100%) make sure to accept the answer (look for a checkmark near the answer score)

Comment: Hmm, that worked to eliminate the duplicate record, but still lists all notebooks, including the `notebook` with the `note` that has a `note_type` of `check_list`. In the console, I can do `Notebook.notes_without_check_lists.last.notes.last.note_type` and it returns `check_list`.

Comment: @jeepagooster this is not possible, if you use `where.not`

Comment: I updated the original question, because I think I may have worded my it in an odd way. All of the records come back using that query, and I'd like the one notebook record excluded due to it having one task with the check list note type.

Comment: @jeepagooster that's an interesting edit! Don't know how to do that with ActiveRecord yet (even though it is easy to do with pure Ruby, which might be inefficient having big amount of notebooks/notes)

Comment: @jeepagooster until I know how to solve it with AR, posted an edit having Ruby version

Comment: Brilliant! I can use the ruby solution. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @jeepagooster no probs, I am really keen to have a solution with AR, but I do not understand really, why with the `scope` you obtain also notebooks with wrong `notes`.. this feels wrong and it should have worked correctly.